# Create HTM table from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to create a table from a JSON:

```
[
  {
    "title": "example",
    "daymatch": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "date": "18. Februar 2023",
        "name": "sample",
        "accessories": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "accessoriesname": "device",
            "price": "20.0"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "accessoriesname": "deviceTwo",
            "price": "10.0"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "accessoriesname": "deviceThree",
            "price": "56.80"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In the HTML I have created a template

```
<template id="example-template">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
          <table class="table text-center">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="2" class="id">Evaluation</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr id="accessorie">
                <td class="accessoriesname">accessoriesname</td>
                <td class="price">price</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </template>
      <main>
        <div id="example-div"></div>
```

The JavaScript file

```
fetch("example.json")
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })

  .then((users) => {
    const container = document.getElementById("example-div");

    let userList = users[0].daymatch;

    for (let i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
      const elList = userList[i];
      const tmpl = document
        .getElementById("example-template")
        .content.cloneNode(true);
      tmpl.querySelector(".id").innerText = elList.name;
      let userListName = userList[i].accessories;
      var headd = "";
      var bodyy = "";
      for (let x = 0; x < userListName.length; x++) {
        const elName = userListName[x];
        const myList = document.createElement("tr");

        console.log(elName.accessoriesname);
      }
      container.appendChild(tmpl);
    }
  });
```

The values from accessories should appear as single lines in the table. But I can't get to them via the tag template.
How do I get the individual "accessories" into the respective lines?

I get the values via the for loop, but how do I get the eizelen tr

Answer (score 0):

The template’s content in the HTML is a `DocumentFragment` with three child nodes -- the `div` between two `#text` nodes. This code picks out the div element, adds it to the “example-div” element and then calls `querySelector` on the added element to find its `tbody` and `tr` elements. It saves the `tr` element to be used as a template, and then empties the `tbody`. Then it steps through the accessories array, cloning the saved `tr` element template for each item, and adding the cloned row to the `tbody`. It finds each of the row's `td` elements by its class name and sets its value.

```
fetch("example.json")
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((users) => {
        const tmpl = document.getElementById("example-template");

        const container = document.getElementById("example-div");

        const tmplClone = tmpl.content.cloneNode(true);
        const template = container.appendChild(tmplClone.childNodes.item(1));
        const rowTemplate = template.querySelector('tr#accessorie');
        const tbody = template.querySelector('table tbody');
        for (let j = tbody.childNodes.length - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
            tbody.childNodes.item(j).remove();
        }

        let daymatches = users[0].daymatch;

        for (let i = 0; i < daymatches.length; i++) {
            const daymatch = daymatches[i];
            template.querySelector(".id").innerText = daymatch.name;
            let accessories = daymatch.accessories;
            for (let x = 0; x < accessories.length; x++) {
                const accessory = accessories[x];
                const rowClone = rowTemplate.cloneNode(true);
                const row = tbody.appendChild(rowClone);
                row.querySelector('.accessoriesname').innerText = accessory.accessoriesname;
                row.querySelector('.price').innerText = accessory.price;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I still need to understand the process, but I'm on it. 
If there are multiple "daymatch" in the JSON, no new table is created per daymatch.